# Maven and wscompile

Tags: java, ant, maven

Hello I am trying to use wscompile ant task from Maven. I am able to call the ant task using the antrun Maven plugin. But wscompile started complaining:

```
[wscompile] error : com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not available in the classpath..
```

so I added the `tools.jar` as dependency as below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0_22</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

but no luck , so I Googled and got a solution as to add `fork="true"`  to the wscompile task and it worked. Does any one know a better solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to ensure you have a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing to your JDK directory.

For example on Windows:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26
```

or on Linux:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26"
```